How do we define a non-standard model of natural numbers in ZFC, including predecessor operations?
I'm trying to understand how to define a non-standard model of the natural numbers in ZFC.
I know that the existence of non-standard models of arithmetic can be derived from the Gödel Compactness theorem.
In Peano Arithmetic (PA) we introduce a new number c which is greater than any
natural number obtained from $0$ using the successor operation $\text{Succ}(n) = n+1$.
From $c$ we can construct numbers like $c+1$, $c+2$, $c+c$, etc., and also predecessors: $c-1$, $c-2$, and so on.
My question is how to define all this in ZFC.
The standard definition of natural numbers in ZFC is:
$0 = \emptyset$, $1 = \{0\}$, $2=\{0,1\}$, and so on, $\text{Succ}(x) = x \cup \{x\}$.
Since every object in ZFC is a set, a non-standard element $c$ should also be a set.
For successors of element $c$ we can use the same $\text{Succ}$ operation:
$c+1 = \text{Succ}(c) = c \cup \{c\}$
$c+2 = \text{Succ}(c+1) = c \cup \{c\} \cup \{c+1\}$, and so on.
My main question is How do we define the predecessor operation for the element $c$: (e.g., $c-1$, $c-2$)?
I've come up with several ideas on how it can be done:

Think of $c$ as an imaginary number. Like $\sqrt{-1}=i$ ($i$ is just a value that exists).
In such a way, we can say that there exists another set $d$, such that: $\text{Succ}(d) = c$, so $d$ is technically $c-1$.
But doing it all the way down seems to result in a contradiction to the axiom of regularity(foundation).
As set $c$ is an infinite descending sequence: $... \in c-n \in c-n+1 \in ... \in c-2 \in c-1 \in c$.

Redefine the Successor function for elements involving $c$.
I came up with 2 approaches here.



The first is to find a set to represent minus (somewhat similar to most significant bit in programming).
For example, set $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$, which is the least set, which does not represent a number.

For example:
$-1 = - \cup 1 = \{\{0\}\} \cup 1 = \{\{\{0\}\}, 0\}$
$c-1 = \{c\} \cup - \cup \{1\} = \{c\} \cup \{\{\{0\}\}, 1\}$

The second is similar to the bijection between naturals and integers:
$0 \rightarrow 0$, $1 \rightarrow 1$, $2 \rightarrow -1$, $3 \rightarrow 2$, $4 \rightarrow -2$, etc.

$\text{Succ}(c) = c+1$
$\text{Succ}^2(c) = c-1$
...
$\text{Succ}^{2n+1}(c) = c+n+1$
$\text{Succ}^{2n}(c) = c-n$
Do these approaches seem viable as a definition of predecessors in a non-standard model of arithmetic in ZFC?

This helped me undestand it better: "It is familiar that there are continuum-many pairwise non-
isomorphic countable models of PA. Tennenbaum's Theorem: The standard model is the only recursive model of PA."

Your question suggests that you are overly concerned with what elements of a model actually are. The property of being a nonstandard model of PA (or if true arithmetic, the complete theory of the natural numbers) is isomorphism invariant, so it doesn't matter what its elements are, any more than it matters what the elements of the cyclic group of order $5$ are, or whether real numbers are Dedekind cuts or equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences or whatever.
In particular, there is no reason to expect that in a model of PA, standard or otherwise, we should have $n\in (n+1)$.
And, perhaps counterintuitively, there is a non-standard model of PA whose underlying set is $\mathbb{N}$ itself (but with nonstandard successor, addition, and multiplication operations).
Ok, but when we prove the compactness theorem, we surely do construct a model in ZFC. So what does it look like? Well, it depends on the proof of the compactness theorem you use. I'll mention two popular approaches.

The Henkin construction involves adjoining a countable set of new constant symbols to the language, along with new axioms stating that those constant symbols are witnesses for provable existentially quantified statements, and taking a completion $T^*$ of the resulting theory. The elements of the model are then equivalence classes of constant symbols for the equivalence relation of $T^*$-provable equality. As I pointed out above, it doesn't matter what these constant symbols actually are, but we could take them to be natural numbers, if you like. If you do that, then the elements of the model will be sets of natural numbers, but the successor and predecessor operations will have nothing to do with the usual operations on natural numbers.

Another popular proof uses ultraproducts. Here, when we build a non-standard model of PA, you can take it to be an ultrapower of $\mathbb{N}$ by a non-principal ultrafilter $U$. The elements of the model will be equivalence classes of infinite sequences of natural numbers, where the non-standard elements are equivalence classes of unbounded sequences. A non-zero element will be represented by a sequence that is non-zero on a $U$-large set of coordinates. Then the predecessor operation just takes predecessor on all coordinates where the sequence is non-zero.


As you can see, neither of these options produces a model where the successor and predecessor operations look anything like the set-theoretic successor operation on ordinals.

Seems, I was really overly conserned with the actual structure. Thanks you for pointing that out!
I'll try to clariy one thing to make sure I got it right.
PA can be embeded into ZFC, and arithmetic operations can be defined on the sets to satisfy PA axioms.
A non-standard model of PA can be also embeded into ZFC. However, under such embeding, the "standard" part of PA may not correspond to the previous embeding of PA into ZFC. Therefore, all elements and operations in embeding of a non-standard model of PA into ZFC can be completely different.

Correct. But a comment on terminology: ZFC is a theory, not a structure, so it doesn't make sense to talk about another theory (PA) or a structure (a non-standard model of PA) being embedded in ZFC. Instead, we could say that ZFC interprets PA or (stronger) that ZFC proves PA has models, both standard and non-standard. @ArtemHak

Thanks a lot!!!
